# Cannot import zmq in python (install issue)

Tags: python, macos, installation, zeromq, pyzmq

I can't seem to install pyzmq on my macbook (OSX 10.9.1)

First call was to run:

```
sudo pip install pyzmq
```

There was an error that libzmq couldn't be found, and it appeared to try and compile the bundled version:

```
jono@air:~ $ sudo pip install pyzmq
Password:
Downloading/unpacking pyzmq
  Downloading pyzmq-14.0.1.tar.gz (867kB): 867kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyzmq

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/gh-pages'
    warning: no directories found matching 'bundled/uuid'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/uuid/Makefile*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/zeromq/src/Makefile*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/zeromq/src/platform.hpp'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'setup.cfg'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'zmq/libzmq*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.deps/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.mailmap' found anywhere in distribution
Installing collected packages: pyzmq
  Running setup.py install for pyzmq
    Did not find libzmq via pkg-config:
    Package libzmq was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libzmq.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libzmq' found

    xcrun clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -c build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/scratch/check_sys_un.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/scratch/check_sys_un.o
    xcrun clang -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/scratch/check_sys_un.o -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/scratch/check_sys_un
    Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
        Custom ZMQ dir:
    ************************************************
    xcrun clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Izmq/utils -Izmq/backend/cython -Izmq/devices -c build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.o
    build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.c:4:10: fatal error: 'zmq.h' file not found
    #include "zmq.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.

    error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1

    Failed with default libzmq, trying again with /usr/local
    Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
        Custom ZMQ dir:       /usr/local
    ************************************************
    xcrun clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/include -Izmq/utils -Izmq/backend/cython -Izmq/devices -c build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.o
    build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.c:4:10: fatal error: 'zmq.h' file not found
    #include "zmq.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.

    error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1

    Warning: Failed to build or run libzmq detection test.

    If you expected pyzmq to link against an installed libzmq, please check to make sure:

        * You have a C compiler installed
        * A development version of Python is installed (including headers)
        * A development version of ZMQ >= 2.1.4 is installed (including headers)
        * If ZMQ is not in a default location, supply the argument --zmq=<path>
        * If you did recently install ZMQ to a default location,
          try rebuilding the ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`
          or specify zmq's location with `--zmq=/usr/local`

    If you expected to get a binary install (egg), we have those for
    current Pythons on OS X and Windows. These can be installed with
    easy_install, but PIP DOES NOT SUPPORT EGGS.

    You can skip all this detection/waiting nonsense if you know
    you want pyzmq to bundle libzmq as an extension by passing:

        `--zmq=bundled`

    I will now try to build libzmq as a Python extension
    unless you interrupt me (^C) in the next 10 seconds...

    ************************************************
 1...
    Using bundled libzmq
    already have bundled/zeromq
    attempting ./configure to generate platform.hpp
    Warning: failed to configure libzmq:
    /bin/sh: ./configure: No such file or directory

    staging platform.hpp from: buildutils/include_darwin
    ************************************************
    cc -c /tmp/crypto_box_keypairpmO9ft.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/tmp/crypto_box_keypairpmO9ft.o
    /tmp/crypto_box_keypairpmO9ft.c:1:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    main (int argc, char **argv) {
    ^~~~
    /tmp/crypto_box_keypairpmO9ft.c:2:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'crypto_box_keypair' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        crypto_box_keypair();
        ^
    2 warnings generated.
    cc build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/tmp/crypto_box_keypairpmO9ft.o -lsodium -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/a.out
    ld: library not found for -lsodium
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    Warning: libsodium not found, zmq.CURVE security will be unavailable
    ************************************************
    building 'zmq.libzmq' extension
    xcrun clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ibundled/zeromq/include -Ibundled -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c buildutils/initlibzmq.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/buildutils/initlibzmq.o
...
... (lots more compiling)
...
    xcrun clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/zmq/backend/cython/utils.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/zmq/backend/cython/utils.so

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/gh-pages'
    warning: no directories found matching 'bundled/uuid'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/uuid/Makefile*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/zeromq/src/Makefile*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'setup.cfg'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'zmq/libzmq*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.deps/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.mailmap' found anywhere in distribution
Successfully installed pyzmq
Cleaning up...
```

This didn't work:

```
jono@air:~ $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 15 2013, 22:53:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.27)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zmq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    _libzmq = ctypes.CDLL(bundled[0], mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.so, 10): Symbol not found: __ZNSiD0Ev
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.so
>>>
```

So I interpreted the errors in the install process as not having libzmq. Following the instructions at https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/wiki/Building-and-Installing-PyZMQ, I uninstalled it, and tried:

```
jono@air:~ $ brew install zeromq
==> Downloading http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-3.2.3.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file tests/test_disconnect_inproc.cpp
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/3.2.3
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
To install the zmq gem on 10.6 with the system Ruby on a 64-bit machine,
you may need to do:

    ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install zmq -- --with-zmq-dir=/usr/local/opt/zeromq
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/3.2.3: 54 files, 2.4M, built in 52 seconds
```

Followed by:

```
jono@air:~ $ sudo pip install pyzmq
Password:
Downloading/unpacking pyzmq
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyzmq

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/gh-pages'
    warning: no directories found matching 'bundled/uuid'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/uuid/Makefile*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/zeromq/src/Makefile*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'setup.cfg'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'zmq/libzmq*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.deps/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.mailmap' found anywhere in distribution
Installing collected packages: pyzmq
  Running setup.py install for pyzmq
    Using bundled libzmq
    already have bundled/zeromq
    already have platform.hpp
    ************************************************
    cc -c /tmp/crypto_box_keypairLbTEQR.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/tmp/crypto_box_keypairLbTEQR.o
    /tmp/crypto_box_keypairLbTEQR.c:1:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    main (int argc, char **argv) {
    ^~~~
    /tmp/crypto_box_keypairLbTEQR.c:2:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'crypto_box_keypair' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        crypto_box_keypair();
        ^
    2 warnings generated.
    cc build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/tmp/crypto_box_keypairLbTEQR.o -lsodium -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/a.out
    ld: library not found for -lsodium
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    Warning: libsodium not found, zmq.CURVE security will be unavailable
    ************************************************

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/gh-pages'
    warning: no directories found matching 'bundled/uuid'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/uuid/Makefile*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/zeromq/src/Makefile*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'setup.cfg'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'zmq/libzmq*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.deps/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.mailmap' found anywhere in distribution
Successfully installed pyzmq
Cleaning up...
```

I keep getting the error:

```
>>> import zmq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    _libzmq = ctypes.CDLL(bundled[0], mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.so, 10): Symbol not found: __ZNSiD0Ev
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/libzmq.so
```

Regardless of what I do.

Comment: MacPorts works great for me when installing/updating pyzmq, at least on 10.8. The setup can take a little while, but if you really need this lib it might be worth it...

Comment: On my old machine, I tried using macports, and homebrew at the same time, and had huge headaches. Will keep in mind the next time I have to decide between homebrew and macports ;)

Comment: I had the same issue when I first got my Mac, and decided to go with Macports, just because of the huge range of packages they offer, and the speed with which they keep them up to date with new releases. I almost never have dependency issues, unlike brew. To each his own, I guess :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much effort, I went back to basics and managed to get it working by:

Building from source with:

```
brew install zeromq
...
python setup.py configure --zmq=/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/4.0.3/
...
sudo python setup.py install
...
```

or

```
sudo port install 
...
```

I have no idea why the standard methods didn't work, but at least I have pyzmq working :)

Answer (score 0):

Got similar ImportError exceptions with OSX/MacPorts, installing the ZeroMQ lib with `sudo port install zeromq` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a lot of time with this problem, finally this worked for me:

- `brew install zeromq`
- find the foulder where `libzmq.pc` is hidden (Example in my case: `Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/pkgconfig`)
- then make:

  ```
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=<path_found_above>
  ```

  Example in my case:

  ```
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/pkgconfig
  ```

Comment: Weclome to stack overflow! Thanks for contributing. All first posts go for a review and I saw this one.  I made a few edits to suit the formatting style of the site a bit more - please feel free to [check them](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28812103/revisions) to see how I got the code block formatting etc.

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is the python installed is compiled with "--enable-unicode=ucs4",

```
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_config_var('Py_UNICODE_SIZE')
>>> 4
```

and a solution to recompile python is described here in https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/issues/257#issuecomment-195836492
if you use pyenv.

```
$pyenv uninstall 2.7.11
$PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-unicode=ucs2" pyenv install 2.7.11
```

then recreate your virtualenv, reinstall every package...