# Can't install PyZMP for Python -- Dependencies

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, zeromq, pyzmq

I am having trouble installing the PyZMP dependency for iPython. I have tried a number of things such as using pip/brew, but ended up installing the package manually using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22209808/2778150).

Now, `pip list packages` yields the following

```
pyzmq (14.2.0-dev)
pyzmq-static (2.2)
```

(I have also tried using pyzmq-static).

Also, my python eggs are clearly present in the proper location:

```
ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ | grep "pyzmq"
pyzmq-14.2.0_dev-py2.7.egg-info
pyzmq_static-2.2-py2.7.egg-info
```

Furthermore:

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python

echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/lib/python:
```

However, when I try to import

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 20 2014, 17:55:13)
In [1]: import pyzmq
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2faa556e5dc0> in <module>()
----> 1 import pyzmq

ImportError: No module named pyzmq
```

Any help troubleshooting would be much apprecaited!

Update: I am able to list the zmq modules in python, but not the pyzmq modules:

```
>>help('modules zmq')

Here is a list of matching modules.  Enter any module name to get more help.

buildutils - utilities for building pyzmq.
buildutils.constants - script for generating files that involve repetitive 
            updates for zmq constants.
buildutils.detect - Detect zmq version
zmq - Python bindings for 0MQ.
...
zmqversion - A simply script to scrape zmq.h for the zeromq version.
IPython.consoleapp - A minimal application base mixin for all ZMQ based 
            IPython frontends.
IPython.html.base.zmqhandlers - Tornado handlers for WebSocket <-> ZMQ sockets.
...
IPython.utils.zmqrelated - Utilities for checking zmq versions.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use:

```
import zmq
```

instead of

```
import pyzmq
```

have a look at the official Examples at https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/blob/master/examples/

Comment: mm, for some reason some packages that required pyzmq as a dependency were still crashing with an import error, but restarting the terminal seemed to have fixed it. I guess I had successfully installed

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled getting IPython (Jupyter) installed, especially with the pyzmq dependency.  In the end, I found a method that worked for me (in Ubuntu) with much less hassle:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libtool pkg-config build-essential autoconf automake python-dev 
$ sudo apt-get build-dep matplotlib 
$ sudo pip install matplotlib 
$ sudo pip install "ipython[all]"
```